# Google Maps API daily request limit reached

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have enabled pay as you go pricing on my Google account and I am sending an API key with all my Google Maps Geocoding requests however I am still receiving this error message

> You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console

I have checked the quota page on the API dashboard and I am well below the limit of 100,000 per day. My key is only used for this geocoding script and this is not the same as the rate limit error which I sometimes receive.

Is there another limit I am unaware of? Can the quota page of the console be relied upon?

Comment: How are you "sending the key"?

Comment: In the url eg.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2605,+My+Address,+Chicago,+Illinois&sensor=false&key=mykey

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing 50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side, you shouldn't have this problem.

" My key is only used for this geocoding script and this is not the same as the rate limit error which I sometimes receive."

what do you mean with this? are you using more than one API key? 
which APIs are you using? only Geocoding?

Comment: Only using 1 api key and I'm only using the geocoding api.